# IllegalStateException when sending multipart mail from tomcat6

Tags: java, grails, ubuntu, tomcat6, jakarta-mail

I'm sending multipart mails with attachment from my grails application using the [mail plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mail).

On my local machine (Mac OS X) all works fine. If I deploy my app to tomcat6 (Ubuntu - ) the mail could not be sent due to an `IllegalStateException`:

```
Stacktrace follows: 
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not in multipart mode - 
   create an appropriate MimeMessageHelper via a constructor that takes a 'multipart' 
   flag if you need to set alternative texts or add inline elements or attachments. 
      at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageBuilder.doAdd(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:347) 
      at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageBuilder.attach(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:308) 
      at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageBuilder.attach(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:284) 
      at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageBuilder.attachBytes(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:280)
      ...
```

Simple mails (not multipart) could be sent from tomat6 successfully.

Here is my code for sending multipart mails:

```
mailService.sendMail {
   multipart true
   to mail
   subject mySubject
   body (view: myView, model: myModel)
   attachBytes "${myTitle}.pdf", CH.config.grails.mime.types['pdf'], myBytes
}
```

What can I do to avoid these Exception?

Where is the underlying JavaMail lib located? Is it packed into war file?

How can I find out which version of JavaMail is used within my tomcat6 and on my local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the problem - it was a stupid mistake of my own.

The call of the `mailService` was encapsulated into another service to add a default `bcc` in the following way:

```
def sendWithBcc(Closure callable) {
    // build a wrapper closure around the standard mail closure, which adds BCC functionality
    def newMailClosure = {
        if(CH.config.extraMail.bcc) {
            bcc(CH.config.extraMail.bcc)
        }

        // set the delegate of the inner closure to the delegate of this closure and call the inner closure
        callable.delegate = delegate
        callable.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        callable.call()
    }

    return mailService.sendMail(newMailClosure)
}
```

On my local machine all works fine because I havn't specified `extraMail.bcc`.

Just in the moment when the `bcc` is set, the multipart property of the outer closure seems to be ignored within the `MailMessageBuilder`.

The solution was to change the position of the `bcc` as shown below:

```
def sendWithBcc(Closure callable) {
    // build a wrapper closure around the standard mail closure, which adds BCC functionality
    def newMailClosure = {            
        // set the delegate of the inner closure to the delegate of this closure and call the inner closure
        callable.delegate = delegate
        callable.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        callable.call()

        if(CH.config.extraMail.bcc) {
            bcc(CH.config.extraMail.bcc)
        }
    }

    return mailService.sendMail(newMailClosure)
}
```

Shame on me - next time I will post more precise code.